# Display subscribe to group on access denied page

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am using [Drupal 7.25](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.25) (I need to update to 7.26) and [organic groups](https://drupal.org/project/og) 7.x-2.4.  I currently have public and private groups working.  I have two users (admin and a normal user).  I have a menu tab that opens the og list (/og-list) view which lists all groups (public and private).

When logged in as a normal user if I click on a public group it shows a subscribe to group link.  That's great.  However, if I click on a private group it gives me the Access denied page without a subscribe link.

I would like to have any normal user be able to click a private group and have it display a link to subscribe.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

Not sure how you have your group node page setup but what I have done is use a node view panel.  In that panel I added the Field: Group (group_group) in a region then set the formatter to "OG subscribe link".  That will display the "Subscribe to group" link when a user clicks on the group they are not a member of.  Since you are getting access denied I'm guessing your group node page is not setup that way.

Another option is to modify the og-list view and add the field "Content: Group".  Then change its Formatter to "OG subscribe link".  That will create a new column in the view that will display a link called "Subscribe to group" for groups you are not a member of and "Unsubscribe to group" for groups you are a member of.

Comment: I have the Field: Group(group_group) in my panel and the "subscribe to group" link shows up when a normal user views a public group.  However it is still missing when they click on a private group.  I also tried option 2 with the same outcome.

The outcome still shows the Access denied page and a Navigation panel

Comment: On a second note.  On my show all groups page I have two fields.  Content: Title and Field:Group(Subscribe).

This shows the group (public and private) as well as the ability to subscribe to it.